# Change the Date Format before setText of TextView

Tags: java, android, date

I using DatePicker for to choose the date.Everything going good. But the problem is to Format the date.

```
// display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview    
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append(" "));
    // Month is 0 based, just add 1

}
```

As per Code i am getting the OUTPUT: 2016-8-22
but
My expected output is 2016-08-22(I want month like this 08)

Thank you,
regards,
Karthi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
tvDisplayDate.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

For more Information about SimpleDateFormat see the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you

```
public static String updateDate(int day, int month, int year) {

    String monthformatted = "";
    if (month < 10)
        monthformatted = "0" + month;
    else
        monthformatted = String.valueOf(month);

    String dayformatted = "";
    if (day < 10)
        dayformatted = "0" + day;
    else
        dayformatted = String.valueOf(day);

    // Append in a StringBuilder
    String aDate = new StringBuilder().append(year).append('-')
            .append(monthformatted).append("-").append(dayformatted).toString();

    return aDate;
}
```

and called this method like

`tvDisplayDate.setText(updateDate(day,month+1,year));`

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat class.. There are a lot of ways to do it..

something like this..

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy"); 
// you can add any format..

 Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDate);
```

Comment: OP wants to Format the date, not parsing

Answer (score 0):

You can append zero using String formation

```
String.format("%02d", month);  

// display current date

public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// set current date into textview    
tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(String.format("%02d", month+ 1)).append("-").append(day).append(" "));
// Month is 0 based, just add 1
```

}

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
tvDisplayDate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
```

Add this and You will succeed

Answer (score 0):

```
// display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String formattedDate = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d-%02d-%02d", year, (month + 1), day);
    tvDisplayDate.setText(formattedDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String format will help you ...

```
String month=String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
String day=String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
String year=String.format("%02d",cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String full_date =  month+ "-" + day + "-" +year ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.US);
tvDisplayDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date().getTime()));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to set date as you want

```
tvDisplayDate.setText(String.format("%04d-%02d-%0d,year,month,date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString()
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old legacy classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Be sure to specify a time zone. If omitted your JVM’s current zone is implicitly applied. That default varies, even *during* runtime. Better to be specific.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Or specify the year, month, day-of-month.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 2 );
```

The month number is sane, 1-12 for January-December. Alternatively you can pass a `Month` enum object instead of mere integer.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 2 );
```

## Generate String

The java.time classes use standard ISO formats when parsing and generating strings. That happens to be your desired format.

```
String output = today.toString();
```

Same format can be parsed.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-02" );
```